Remove attachments from a mail before saving it as eml file using EAgetmail package is not working
I want to remove attachments from a mail before saving it as .eml file using EAGetMail package is not working for me, here is my code:
` 
   _mail = new("EAGetMailLicence");
   _mail.Load(memoryStream.ToArray());

   if (_mail.Attachments.Length > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _mail.Attachments.Length; i++)
            {
                 _mail.RemoveAttachment(_mail.Attachments[i]);
                //_mail.Attachments[i] = null;


            }

            _mail.Update();


        }
      //save .eml file`

The .eml file is saved but it contain always the attachments.
I tried:
_mail.Attachments[i] = null
and
Array.Clear(_mail.Attachments);
but attachments are not removed

I used MimeKit package.I can remove attachments successfully with MimeKit
